# Processos em linux(fork())

Tags: c

Estou criando um servidor do tipo cliente/servidor usando *sockets tcp*, um cliente se conecta ao servidor, quando fecha a aplicação cliente, o servidor fecha a conexão comando **close(conexao)**, porém o processo no servidor que abriu aquela porta ainda esta conectado aquela porta, mesmo após o close.

Como posso fechar essa porta sem matar o processo?

**Obs:** tentei criar um processo filho e de lá fechar a porta usando `fuser -k porta/tcp`, mas com esse comando ele mata qualquer processo que esteja conectado a porta que recebeu *kill* por *fuser*, assim ele mata o pai e o filho e o programa encerra(Morto).

Se uso *thread* e dou `pthread_exit` na *thread* que abriu a conexão *socket* na tal porta, o programa também encerra(Morto).

Alguém tem dica do que fazer?

Comment: Veja este exemplo: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13669474/multiclient-server-using-fork

Comment: Obrigado pleo contato Isalamon. Na verdade, no meu codigo ate agora consigo suportar muiltplis clientes atraves de um array de sockets, o problema e que se o cliente fecha sua apliacao e entra de novo, como a porta esta bloqueada ele nao consiguira se conectar, o que me obrigara a reinciar o servidor, e isso que quero contornar, assim que um cliente fechar sua conexao, o servidor matar o processo que estava usando aquela porta e abrir de novo!

Comment: Isalamon, no exemplo que me passou, alguem comenta que "
Pode e / ou deve a criança processar também o fecho? Eu pergunto, porque eu estou correndo para o problema onde eu tenho um processo filho em execução em um loop e depois mata o pai e tente reiniciá-lo, no entanto, não pode vincular o soquete desde que o processo filho ainda tem o soquete do servidor vinculado", e esse meu problema, como o soquete esta vinculado ao filho e ao pai, os dois morrem, como faco esta desvinculacao sem ninguem precisar morrer, ou apenas um?

Comment: Veja este outro exemplo, no final há o um arquivo de server completo usando fork: http://www.cs.rpi.edu/~moorthy/Courses/os98/Pgms/socket.html